# Unknown error while using DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am trying to use DrawerLayout from Support library using [official](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) tutorial but whenever I tried to run my application I got crash .After reading the below logs I am not able to identify the location in my code which is responsible for this crash.

```
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1340)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1789)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:656)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:722)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1624)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1172)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7080)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:672)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7080)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7080)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7080)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1056)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1738)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:426)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    ... 29 more
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/primary_text_dark.xml from drawable resource ID #0x0
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1725)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1902)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:432)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    ... 33 more
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/primary_text_dark.xml from xml type drawable resource ID #0x0
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1952)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1720)
06-16 21:14:55.272: E/AndroidRuntime(20104):    ... 36 more
```

---

**My Layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

**My drawer_list_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

If More information is required then please comment and I will update the question.

Comment: Did you change something in the example code?

Comment: @Ahmad I only changed the fragment and everything else is same.

Comment: Can you please add the code to the question?

Comment: Check `res/color/primary_text_dark.xml` exists and regenerate `R.Java`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happened to face the same problem yesterday. And here's what I did to fix that.

Only problem is of the `TextView` that you are using to inflate your list Item. So if you are using something like

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, listarray));
```

Just replace it with

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listarray));
```

and it should work.

EDT: If you are using the same code for a target like android 2.2 or 2.3, you should remove these lines from your

> drawer_list_item.xml

```
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be coming from your `ListView` that you have inside of the `DrawerLayout`, not from the `DrawerLayout` itself. Somewhere in your row layout, you are referring to `@color/primary_text_dark`, and that color does not exist in your project.

Comment: I could find anything related to @color/primary_text_dark in my listitem.I have checked it twice and also added xml code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same symptoms, fixed by changing the array adapter constructor from:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getContext(),
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mDrawerTitles));
```

to:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mDrawerTitles);
```

Not exactly sure why but by passing the Activity as a Context in the constructor, everything went back to normal.