# Android.view.inflateException Binary XML file line #7 Error inflating class<unknown>

Tags: android, xml

This question has been asked previously. Problem is same but the answers couldn't solve my problem.
this question [Unknown error while using DrawerLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135106/unknown-error-while-using-drawerlayout) has same problem like me and i tried the steps given but no luck.i have layout file:
activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>  

<!-- as the main content the following view takes the whole space for content display..using match_parent in both the sections -->

<FrameLayout

    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells the Drawerlayout to treat this as the sliding drawer on the left side for the left-to-right 
language...and on right side for the right-to-left languages..a solid contrast is used to differentiate it from the content view.. -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#ffff"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The logcat says `android.view.InflateException:Binary XML file line #7:Error inflating class<unknown>`..
I have added support library and tried the solution given to that question but i couldnot solve the issue ..

Comment: check the library checkbox in order and export tab under build Path .

Comment: Run the [Android lint tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html); it should be able to pinpoint the source of the problem.

Comment: add the android supportv4.jar is not according to your sdk version. Please add the same vesrion with sdk